# как скрыть показ всех div классов

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap, frontend

Хотел отображать только по однаму элементу div . Но при загрузки страницы все отображаются . как решить эту проблему ?

```js
// portfolio filter
 $(window).load(function(){'use strict';
  var $portfolio_selectors = $('.portfolio-filter >li>a');
  var $portfolio = $('.portfolio-items');
  $portfolio.isotope({
   itemSelector : '.portfolio-item',
   layoutMode : 'cellsByRow'
  });
  
  $portfolio_selectors.on('click', function(){
   $portfolio_selectors.removeClass('active');
   $(this).addClass('active');
   var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
   $portfolio.isotope({ filter: selector });
   return false;
  });
 });
```

```css
#portfolio {
  padding: 100px 0;
  background: #f5f5f5;
}
#portfolio .portfolio-filter {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 0 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}
#portfolio .portfolio-filter > li {
  float: left;
  display: block;
}
#portfolio .portfolio-filter > li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 7px 15px;
  background: #e5e5e5;
  color: #64686d;
  position: relative;
}
#portfolio .portfolio-filter > li a:hover,
#portfolio .portfolio-filter > li a.active {
  background: #45aed6;
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 -3px 0 0 #318daf inset;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 -3px 0 0 #318daf inset;
}
#portfolio .portfolio-filter > li a.active:after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -17px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -10px;
  border-width: 10px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #318daf transparent transparent transparent;
}
#portfolio .portfolio-filter > li:first-child a {
  border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
}
#portfolio .portfolio-filter > li:last-child a {
  border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
}
#portfolio .portfolio-items {
  margin: 15px;
}
#portfolio .portfolio-item {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  padding: 25px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -o-box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#portfolio .portfolio-item .portfolio-item-inner {
  position: relative;
}
#portfolio .portfolio-item .portfolio-item-inner .portfolio-info {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 400ms;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: #fff;
}
#portfolio .portfolio-item .portfolio-item-inner .portfolio-info h3 {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1;
  margin: 0;
  color: #fff;
}
#portfolio .portfolio-item .portfolio-item-inner .portfolio-info .preview {
  position: absolute;
  top: -18px;
  right: 12px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(90deg, #2caab3 0%, #2c8cb3 100%);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, #2caab3 0%, #2c8cb3 100%);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(90deg, #2caab3 0%, #2c8cb3 100%);
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  line-height: 36px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #fff;
}
#portfolio .portfolio-item:hover .portfolio-info {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<section id="portfolio">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="section-header">
                <h2 class="section-title text-center wow fadeInDown">Our Works</h2>
                <p class="text-center wow fadeInDown">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut <br> et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam</p>
            </div>

            <div class="text-center">
                <ul class="portfolio-filter">
                    <li><a class="active" href="#" data-filter="*">All Works</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-filter=".lan1">lan1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-filter=".lan2">lan2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-filter=".portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
                </ul><!--/#portfolio-filter-->
            </div>

            <div class="portfolio-items">
                <div class="portfolio-item lan1">
                <div class=".col-xs-9">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae perferendis, alias, incidunt rem quas quam iure, ipsam labore esse optio minima commodi soluta, similique qui explicabo saepe aut doloribus harum!</p>
                </div>
                </div><!--/.portfolio-item-->
            </div>
            <div class="portfolio-items">
                <div class="portfolio-item lan2">
                <div class=".col-xs-9">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae perferendis, alias, incidunt rem quas quam iure, ipsam labore esse optio minima commodi soluta, similique qui explicabo saepe aut doloribus harum!</p>
            </div>
                </div><!--/.portfolio-item-->
            </div>
        </div><!--/.container-->
    </section><!--/#portfolio-->
```

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте к CSS стилям элементов, которые хотите скрыть со страницы `display:none;` или добавьте специальный стиль

```
.hidden-element {
    display:none;
}
```

и добавьте имя этого стиля к элементам, которые хотите спрятать например так:

```
<div class="text-center hidden-element">...</div>
```

или в JavaScript:

```
var div = document.querySelector('.text-center');
div.classList.toggle('hidden-element');
```

PS: метод `toggle` у `classList` добавляет имя класса к элементу если его нет и удаляет если он есть

Comment: да спасибо ваши рение я бы хотел использовать но к сожалению они и еще должны отбражатся при шелчке , а не спрятать их полностью

Comment: Вот последний абзац моего ответа как раз для этого